# Non-Stateful LSTM Issues with Keras

Tags: keras, sequential

Good day,

I am trying to create a LSTM model (stateful or non-stateful) but running into several issues.

I am attempting to add a layer using:

```
model = Sequential()
...    
model.add(LSTM(c['num_rnn_unit'],
                           activation=c['rnn_activation'],
                           dropout=c['dropout_rnn_input'],
                           recurrent_dropout=c['dropout_rnn_recurrent'],
                           return_sequences=True,
                           stateful=False,  
                           #batch_input_shape=(c['batch_size'],c['num_steps'], c['input_dim'])  
                           ))
```

where:

```
'num_rnn_unit': np.random.choice([16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024])

'rnn_activation': np.random.choice(['tanh', 'sigmoid'])

'dropout_rnn_input': 0

'batch_size': np.random.choice([64, 128])

'num_steps':np.random.choice([5, 10, 15])

'input_dim': 64
```

I experimented with "stateful=True" and used the commented out "batch_input_shape" but this caused additional errors, which others have had as well but found no workable solution. 
So I stuck with trying to make "stateful=False" to work but it yields the error (below).

Any thoughts on why this error is coming up? Thanks in advance!

**Here is the traceback**:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    180                 self.inputs = network.get_source_inputs(self.outputs[0])
    181         elif self.outputs:
--> 182             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    183             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    184                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    539 
    540         if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 541             return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    542 
    543         # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    487             # Actually call the layer,
    488             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 489             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    490             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    491 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
   1689                                      mask=mask,
   1690                                      training=training,
-> 1691                                      initial_state=initial_state)
   1692 
   1693     @property

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state, constants)
    635             mask = mask[0]
    636 
--> 637         if len(initial_state) != len(self.states):
    638             raise ValueError('Layer has ' + str(len(self.states)) +
    639                              ' states but was passed ' +

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\env_py3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in states(self)
    436                 num_states = 1
    437             else:
--> 438                 num_states = len(self.cell.state_size)
    439             return [None for _ in range(num_states)]
    440         return self._states

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

**Would this be the first layer "input_shape", with batch_normalization=True:**

```
 if c['batch_normalization']:
        model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(c['num_steps'], c['input_dim'])))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(c['dropout_input']),
                              input_shape=(c['num_steps'], c['input_dim'])))
```

Comment: Have you tried passing in the `input_shape` argument to the first layer?

Comment: I've tried that with the stateful=True case the adding the batch_input_shape parameter.

Comment: I've added more details in the question - is that the first layer add?

Comment: So in the edit you posted, you don't have the `LSTM`. Shouldn't that be there?